# Customize a SharePoint view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I created a SharePoint 2013 list and I retrieve the list content. Now I want to personalize my view according to my design. How can I do that knowing that the coding is my final solution?

Comment: Please provide more details on what customization you need.Then only one can decide whether you can do it OOTB or need to change the query through code

Comment: I want to modify the style of my list, for example i want to show the image in the right under the title, and the content in the left etc..